# Completely vs Fully?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In my recent paper, there a question:

**"When you read something in a foreign language, you frequently come across words you do not______understand."**

**A. totally   B. completely      C.wholly       D. fully**

My answer is **B**, but the right answer is **D**.I've tried look up the difference between "completely" and "fully", but their meanings all sound the same! Could you guys explain it for me?

Comment: All the answers seem fine on the face of it (apart from C being capitalized).  Perhaps there is more context around the question which you have not included, which would favour one answer over another.

Comment: What was the question exactly? All options are correct (although I'm not fond of 'totally' here).

Comment: Hmm I just typed the whole sentence for you guys. yeah i think there's no  difference between 4 choices, but we have to choose one only. It's multiple choice test you know :/

Comment: Looks like this question has been causing confusion for some years - see [here](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/809100571) and [here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/PassageAboutReading/pxdvq/post.htm). All conclusions appear to reflect what's been said here (although I lean towards *wholly* for some reason).

Comment: :/ there must be something wrong with the question :/

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+totally+understand%2Cnot+completely+understand%2Cnot+wholly+understand%2Cnot+fully+understand&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20totally%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20completely%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20wholly%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20fully%20understand%3B%2Cc0), ***fully*** is far more common for this exact context. But there's no real difference in meaning between the choices - it's just a matter of established idiomatic preference.

Comment: When you sit some exams, you frequently come across questions you do not______understand. The fault quite possibly lies with the examiners.

Comment: It's a very poor exam.  While *fully* may be the most popular choice, there are contexts where one might choose one of the others to better effect.  It's choices like this that make the difference between good writing and great writing.

Answer (score -1):

As the ngrams from FumbleFingers show *fully* is more common. Although the aggregated feel for language of all commenters agrees that all are acceptable.

[image]